Lerch Transcendent and Arcsin relation
Just discovered very interesting relation between Lerch Transcendent $\Phi(z,s,a)$ and $\arcsin(x)$.
If we define:
$$p(x)=4x^3-3x+i (1-4x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2} $$ $$p^*(x)=4x^3-3x-i (1-4x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
$$s(x)=2x^2-1 + 2ix\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ $$s^*(x)=2x^2-1 - 2ix\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
then
$$\arcsin(x)=\frac{4 x}{\pi }+\frac{1}{2 \pi }\left(p(x) \Phi\left(s^*(x),2,\frac{3}{2}\right)+p^*(x) \Phi\left(s(x),2,\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)$$
for real $x$ with $|x|<1$.
I am just very curious is there any other function representation using Lerch Transcendent? If so is there any theory behind that.

Just an addition for $\sin(x)$ there is similar formula for $|x|\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ (corrected according to comment of @Claude Leibovici).
$$\sin (x)=\frac{\pi  x}{4}-\frac{1}{8} i \left(e^{3 i x} \Phi \left(-e^{2 i x},2,\frac{3}{2}\right)-e^{-3 i x} \Phi \left(-e^{-2 i x},2,\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)$$
of course it can be improved to work for all $x$, just something that says that there would be some method to represent functions via Lerch Transcendent.

Of course the value of the first formula is that it translates polynomials to transcendental function using $\Phi$, while in second one (for $\sin$) it is translation of $\exp$ to $\sin$ which may not be very interesting.

After digging more found that there is another equivalent form:
$$\arcsin(t)=\frac{2 \left(\text{Li}_2\left(t+i \sqrt{1-t^2}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-t+i \sqrt{1-t^2}\right)\right)}{\pi }+\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(2 t^2-1-2 i t \sqrt{1-t^2} \right)-\text{Li}_2\left(2 t^2-1+2 i t\sqrt{1-t^2}\right)}{2 \pi }$$
Now it works for any $t$ and may lead us to some interesting formulas. For example:
$$2 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)-3 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{2\pi^2}{9}$$
or
$$4 \left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2 \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)}+i \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)\right)\right)- \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(-\sqrt{2 \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)}+i \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)\right)\right)\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(1-\sqrt{5}+i \sqrt{2 \left(\sqrt{5}+5\right)}\right)\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(1-\sqrt{5}-i \sqrt{2 \left(\sqrt{5}+5\right)}\right)\right)=\frac{2\pi^2}{5}$$
or
$$\text{Li}_2\left(2 \sqrt{2}-3\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-2 \sqrt{2}-3\right)+4 \left(\text{Li}_2\left(i \left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)\right)- \text{Li}_2\left(i \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)\right)\right)=2\pi i\log \left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)$$
Seems there is something that might be interesting here:
Polylogarithm ladders for the tribonacci and n-nacci constants

One more addition. $\log(s)$ also can be represented in dilog form:
$$2 \pi  i\log(s)= 4 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{i \left(s^2+\sqrt{s^4+2 s^2+1}-1\right)}{2 s}\right)-4 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{i \left(-s^2+\sqrt{s^4+2 s^2+1}+1\right)}{2 s}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{s^4+\sqrt{s^4+2 s^2+1} s^2-\sqrt{s^4+2 s^2+1}+1}{2 s^2}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{s^4-\sqrt{s^4+2 s^2+1} s^2+\sqrt{s^4+2 s^2+1}+1}{2 s^2}\right)$$
Not sure how to switch back to $\Phi$.

Very nice ! Could you explain what have been your steps ?

@ClaudeLeibovici thank you the idea is to represent the Triangle Wave by $(-1)^{\lfloor r\rfloor } \left(\frac{1}{2}-\text{frac}(r)\right)=\frac{4}{\pi ^2} \sum _{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i \sin \left(\pi  (2 i+1) \left(r+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}{(2 i+1)^2}$ and the first part can be converted then to $\arcsin(x)$ and the right side to $\Phi$

The second one works for $|x| \leq \frac \pi 2$ (if I am not wrong)

@ClaudeLeibovici  Thank you. Yes. It should work for $|x| \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Let me correct the body.
